# postgres ERROR: target lists can have at most 1664 entries SQL state: 54000

Tags: errors, postgresql-10

In my query, I want to have more than 1700 columns but I got this error:

```
"ERROR: target lists can have at most 1664 entries SQL state: 54000"
```

I'm using postgres10 on Windows.

Has anyone come across this before? Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: It's a limit in Postgres, see this thread for example: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20080706000420.4d9409f1%40btj-laptop.asp-as.no
It's very unlikely to be changed, so your best bet is to fix your code so it uses less columns.

Comment: Thank you @Colin'tHart, the thread Is old than 10 years, there is no solution from now, I must use concat i think.

Answer (score 1):

Such column count is really **huge**. Without the schema/query details I cannot say, what's the reason, but I might **guess** there are many data columns not really required to be serialized there. Instead doing some concat magic I would suggest to merge such columns into JSON/JSONB objects which would be then easily accessible by the application. This is the classic NoSQL approach in SQL RDBMSes.